# Process CSV in the background hourly with Pandas and APScheduler

Tags: python, function, pandas, apscheduler

I have a CSV File (`ZN_15M`) that I'm trying to use `read_csv` function on hourly. So I have APScheduler installed and am trying to use it to read the CSV file every hour (and some other stuff not shown but if I can get the `read_csv` stuff going the other stuff will work too):

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start() 

def Run():
    f2 = open('C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Exported_Data\ZN_ES\ZN_15M.csv')
    ZN = pd.read_csv(f2)
    #Do stuff to the CSV File/DataFrame
    ZN.tocsv(path_or_buf = 'path')

def main():
    job = scheduler.add_interval_job(Run, minutes=60, args=())
    while True:
        sleep(60)
        sys.stdout.write('.'); sys.stdout.flush()
```

I don't get any errors when I manually run the script, but nothing is running hourly like I'd like. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Update: I'm getting an error below:

```
def process_csv(path_to_csv):
    ZN_ES_comb = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
    # Insert your CSV processing here
    ZN_ES_comb = pd.DataFrame(ZN_ES_comb)
    ZN_ES_comb.to_csv(path_to_csv.replace('.csv', '_modified_{timestamp}.csv').format(
        timestamp=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create CSV for demonstrating purposes
    path_to_csv = 'C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\ZN_ES\ZN_ES_15M\CSV\ZN_ES_comb.csv'
    pd.DataFrame(ZN_ES_comb).to_csv(path_to_csv, index=False)
    # Start scheduler
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.add_job(func=process_csv,
                      args=[path_to_csv],
                      trigger=IntervalTrigger(seconds=2))
    # Wait for 7 seconds so that scheduler can call process_csv 3 times
    time.sleep(7)
```

The error is for the line `pd.DataFrame(ZN_ES_comb).to_csv(path_to_csv, index=False)` - it says:

```
NameError: name 'ZN_ES_comb' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. It should be `ZN.to_csv()` instead of `ZN.tocsv()` in `def Run()`.
2. Parameter value of `time.sleep()` is measured in seconds, not in minutes like you apparently have thought. Thus, during the sleeping `Run()` was not ran at all.

In the following there is a working solution that works with Python 3.5 and APScheduler 3.3.1. `IntervalTrigger()` has also `hours` parameter which you might wanna use instead of `seconds`.

```
import time

import pandas as pd
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger


def process_csv(path_to_csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
    # Insert your CSV processing here
    df.to_csv(path_to_csv.replace('.csv', '_modified_{timestamp}.csv').format(
        timestamp=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create CSV for demonstrating purposes
    path_to_csv = 'made_up.csv'
    pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'banana'],
                  'number': [1, 2]}).to_csv(path_to_csv, index=False)
    # Start scheduler
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.add_job(func=process_csv,
                      args=[path_to_csv],
                      trigger=IntervalTrigger(seconds=2))
    # Wait for 7 seconds so that scheduler can call process_csv 3 times
    time.sleep(7)
```

Comment: Hi Tuomastik, thank you, I'm still getting one error (shown in the edits to the original posting above) and am not sure why. I thought I defined ZN_ES_comb already yet it's not recognizing it...

Comment: In my example I created the CSV only for demonstrating purposes as the comment in the code explains. You already have your own CSV so you can just skip that part. Also, in the `process_csv()` function the `pd.read_csv()` returns `DataFrame` so there is no need for this line `ZN_ES_comb = pd.DataFrame(ZN_ES_comb)`. I have adjusted my code to suit your exact case in this following snippet: https://pastebin.com/rFiaYnD1

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated